# pytest can't mock a method when its called by another module

Tags: python, pytest

I can't seem to mock a method of one of my modules. I can mock it inside the unit test itself, but not in another method that calls it.

```
# Inside a module
from my_module import my_method

def some_method_that_calls_my_module_my_method(arg):
    my_method(arg)

# In my unit test
@patch("my_module.my_method", mock.MagicMock(return_value="test1"))
def test_test():
    # this works
    print(my_module.my_method("slkdjflskdjfl"))

    # this executes the method not the mock
    some_method_that_calls_my_module_my_method("sldkfjlskdjflskdjf")
```

I'll add I really want to use the pytest decorator here if I can- I much prefer it to `with`.

Comment: How does the method-under-test actually refer to the method you are trying to mock?

Comment: ^ just added that to my post

Comment: `some_method...` doesn't use the name `my_module.my_method`; it uses the name `some_other_module.my_method`.

Comment: man this is a stupid question, but how do I get the name of some_other_module? Its named `some_other_module.py`, but trying to change the patch to `"some_other_module.my_module.my_method"` does not working

Comment: It's just `some_other_module.my_method`; your `from ... import ... ` statement created a *new* global variable in that scope initialized from `my_module.my_method`.

Comment: ugh I just figured it out. `some_other_module.my_method` NOT `"some_other_module.my_module.my_method"` like you say. I saw other answers to questions like this but I didn't understand what the right path was.